# Align popover to bottom left

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How could I make the popover bottom div do not go beyond the popover button right side, like in the image:
[image]

Here's my code.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" tabindex="0" class="btn btn" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="<input>">
    Search
</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                     trigger: 'manual',
                     placement: 'bottom',
                     html: true
                  }).click(function (e) {
                     e.preventDefault();
                     $(this).popover('show');
                  });
```

**Bootply:**
http://www.bootply.com/3SLzUgPyrV

Comment: you could try something like this and adapt it to your requirements. http://www.bootply.com/NZRFyE1zPw

Comment: @Sebsemillia, that's what I need, but any way to remove this weird rearranging effect?

Comment: I created an answer with the fix.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try something like this and adapt it to your requirements:

1.) Set the position of the arrow via CSS:

```
.popover.bottom .arrow {
    left:90% !important;
}
```

2.) Set the position of the popover after the click event. With your code example it could look like this:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                 trigger: 'manual',
                 placement: 'bottom',
                 html: true
              }).click(function (e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 // Exibe o popover.
                 $(this).popover('show');

                $('.popover').css('left', '63px'); 
              });
```

[**Working Example**](http://www.bootply.com/5y8iVm8gg4)

Comment: Sebsemillia, there's a problem, if I resize the window, it will not be correctly positioned.

Comment: Yes, of course. My example is just a hint in the right direction. You have to change `$('.popover').css('left', '63px');` to your projects needs. Use percentages and/or calculate the position depending on the viewport width..

Comment: just to leave here as example: `$('.popover').css('left', $(this).offset().left+'px'); $('.popover .arrow').css('left', ($(this).outerWidth()/2)+'px');`

Answer (score 5):

With Bootstrap v4, you can use the 'offset' property provided by Tether:

```
// Enable all popovers and tooltips
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    html: true,
    offset: '0 100px' //offset the popover content
});
```

This will offset the popover content, but you will still need to use CSS to offset the arrow

Comment: Great, thanks for that - it's always best to use built-in features ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to use `bottom-end` placement to align the popover relative to the bottom right of the parent element. However, that's not supported by Bootstrap popover. You'll need to pass that to Popper through `popperConfig` option, this way:

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({

    // ...

    popperConfig: {
        placement: 'bottom-end',
    },
});
```

All the supported placement variations are:

- `top-start`
- `top-end`
- `bottom-start`
- `bottom-end`
- `left-start`
- `left-end`
- `right-start`
- `right-end`

Comment: Great! But unfortunately this loses the arrow (https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/3951)

Answer (score 1):

The way I did it is to use the inserted.bs.popover event and set the offset there, since the width of the popover is unknown until then.  This aligns the popup window to the left of the control:

```
var elWidth = inputElement.width();

inputElement.popover({
    container: 'body',
    animation: true,
    content: Msg,
    placement: 'top',
    trigger: 'hover'
}).on('inserted.bs.popover', function (e) {
    var id = $(this).attr("aria-describedby");
    var popover = $("#" + id);
    popover.data()['bs.popover'].config.offset = parseInt((popover.width() - elWidth) / 2, 10) + 'px';
});
```