# How can I change the position of Bootstrap 4 popovers?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I'm trying to align Bootstrap 4 popovers on the left or right side of their parent button. I know that I could achieve it by using "offset", but that would mean I'd have to set a different offset value for each button as those are never the same width.

Is there some way to utilize popper.js (which BS is using for positioning) to achieve that alignment, instead of always centering the popover?

[For reference, this is the result I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtSHR.png)

Comment: Have you checked the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#four-directions)? You can also have a pop over on the top or bottom.

Comment: Yes I have checked the docs and it does not answer my question. I know I can set the side of the popover, but it will still always center on that side.

Comment: You should be able to append `-start` or `-end` to the directions for aligning the popover. Ex. `bottom-start`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, it's throwing a js error. Seems like these options are supported by popper, but not BS. Here is a quick fiddle: https://codepen.io/ivomynttinen/pen/eeoORa which is working with eg. data-placement="bottom", but not data-placement="bottom-start".

Comment: Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62779470/1128918 on how to use `-start` and `-end` variations with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing around with it for a while I figured out I can achieve what I want by using the offset since it does not only accept pixel values, but also % relative to the parent object.

So I'm just doing:

```
data-offset="-50%"
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are here because you would like to set the offset when using `react-bootstrap`, below is how you do it. By adding `popperConfig` property to the `Dropdown.Menu` component:

```
<Dropdown>
  <Dropdown.Toggle>
    Select Option
  </Dropdown.Toggle>
  <Dropdown.Menu
    popperConfig={{
      modifiers: [
        {
          name: 'offset',
          options: {
            offset: [0, 10],
          },
        },
      ],
    }}>
    <Dropdown.Item>Menu Item 1</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item>Menu Item 2</Dropdown.Item>
  </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

Hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 1):

@Oyalhi's answer brought me to the following idea: If Bootstrap allows allows the 'popperConfig' property, you can also use the 'placement' option provided by popper.js. And indeed: the following code works for my popover using jQuery and Bootstrap 4. The initial placement 'top' is overriden by the 'top-start' while building the tooltip. However, you might have to introduce your own .css because Bootstrap doesn't provide styles for this placement.

```
$('#myElement').popover({
    placement: 'top', 
    content: "some random text",
    popperConfig: {
        placement: 'top-start'
    }
});
```